# Modify function to only return results with "home" in their filename

Tags: php, function

I have the following custom page template filenames:

- template-about-1.php
- template-about-2.php
- template-home-1.php
- template-home-2.php

I have this function to get the page templates:

```
function get_page_templates_select() {
 $teh_cats = get_page_templates();
 foreach ( $teh_cats as $template_name => $template_filename ) {
     $results[] = $template_name;
   }
   return $results;
}
```

How can I modify the function to ONLY return the templates that have "home" in their filename?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out after thinking it through..

```
if (stripos(strtolower($template_filename), 'home') !== false) {
    $results[] = $template_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use:

```
function get_page_templates_select() {
 $teh_cats = get_page_templates();
 foreach ( $teh_cats as $template_name => $template_filename ) {
     if (preg_match('/home/i', $template_filename)) {
         $results[] = $template_name;
     }
   }
   return $results;
}
```